# Updating child record on update of parent field

Tags: trigger, workflow

I have a TestDeploy Object - with field TestDate
When a TestDeploy Object is created 3 task are auto creted using workflow

**Task1 - Subject :- TestDeploy Test1 , due date:- testdate + 30 

Task2 - Subject :- TestDeploy Test2 , due date:- testdate + 40 

Task3 - Subject :- TestDeploy Test3 , due date:- testdate + 50**

Currently, when TestDeploy.TestDate is set and the record is saved, the tasks are created and Task.DueDate is permanently set. 
What should change: If TestDeploy.TestDate is edited, then each Task.DueDate should be re-evaluated. The existing task must be updated with new due date.